# Hide application from smartwatch

Tags: android, wear-os

I have created an application which contains a Wear application in it. This application is automatically installed on the watch when the user installs my application on his phone. This all works great but now I want to give the user the option to hide the smartwatch app from his clock. And that's the point where I get stuck.

So how can I hide an application on the smartwatch without to uninstall it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this would be to have 2 version of your app on Play Store - one that is phone only and other one with both phone and watch apks.